# Install pip dependencies only from conda environment file

Tags: python, pip, conda

I setup a conda environment using `conda env create -f environment.yaml -n new_env_name`, because I wanted a different conda environment name than that stored in `environment.yaml`.

It seems that pip dependencies listed in `environment.yaml` were not all installed, so I would like to install them without starting from scratch. I looked in the documentation but couldn't find a way to do this ; any ideas? :)

Answer (score 0):

After creating and activating your environment do the following, to install packages with the venv pip:

1. install pip to your venv directory with: `conda install pip`
2. install packages with: `/path_to/venv_name/bin/pip install package`